# Synchronous boost converter

Tags: dc-dc-converter, mosfet-driver

I am trying to create a synchronous boost dc-dc converter. I have attached the circuit diagram but I am getting stuck with simulation as a simulation error occurs. The signal generator has a square wave of 5V.  I am using Multisim and there is a popup that says "A simulation error has occurred. Would you like to run the Convergence Assistant to attempt to resolve this problem automatically?" In multisim the voltage across the resistor increases to 2.11V and then the error pops up. Any help would be greatly appreciated.  [image: My attempt at a synchronous boost converter]

Comment: in what are you trying to simulate this? What's the error you're getting?

Comment: @MarcusMüller I am using Multisim and there is a popup that says "A simulation error has occurred. Would you like to run the Convergence Assistant to attempt to resolve this problem automatically?"

Comment: @MarcusMüller it initially increases the voltage across the resistor and once it gets to 2.11V across the resistor then the error pops up

Comment: @Alura That info should go in the question, since it's important to anyone who wants to help

Comment: @pipe, my apologies. I have edited the question to include the info

Comment: @Alura if this is a boost converter shouldn't the inductor be in series with the diode?

Comment: @laptop2d what diode are you referring to? The only diode in this circuit is part of the Mosfet driver. Futhermore, the diode in a non-synchronous boost converter is always connected to the inductor and the switch (In this case the mosfet at the bottom)

Comment: 1nF bootstrap capacitor seems quite low to me. Try between 100n and 1u. Also, as you might know, S1 should be a fast diode. I don't know what diode you placed there.

Comment: @laptop2d If you look at carefully then you'll see that Q2 acts as the diode just like in a conventional boost converter. S1 is the diode which is necessary for bootstrap drivers.

Comment: @RohatKılıç I am using a schottky diode, will that work?

Comment: @Alura Yes. Should be a schottky.

Answer (score -1):

For convergence issues try/play around with different simulation parameters to allow more error/tolerance in your simulation results (minimise tolerance parameters. Here is screenshot of simulation settings of LTSpice.
 [image: here is screenshot of simulation settings of LTSpice]

I have not used multisim, but it should have something similar.

Anyway, it is highly likely that the mosfet driver IC model is your source of error. Before you go any further I suggest you do an simple analog open circuit simulation of your circuit (dont use that driver). Use a comparator and triangular wave to generate your PWM with the right duty cycle and see if your "Boost" works. Always resort to using very less IC models. Try to keep it analog as much as possible.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fDPDn0.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Edit the schematic and try with your values. I don't know Fsw, Vout, Iout, etc.
This schematic editor looks legit, try this one. Pro tip, always use a simulation software that has good community support.
Cheers.

Comment: I have built the circuit you have described above and it is boosting. I am required to boost a 2.7V capacitor to 5V so i increase the duty cycle as the capacitor discharges but the greatest input voltage I can boost to 5V is 1.8V. I decided to use a synchronous boost in order to decrease the lowest voltage from which I can boost to 5V. After building the circuit that I have highlighted in the question I am boosting, however, the output voltage decreases as I increase the duty cycle??? Any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: Looks like you have not sized the inductor optimally. You can usually push your system to around 95% duty cycle without having problems (but not easy). Probably your inductor saturates (starts behaving as a resistor), now your output cap is discharging and your diode has become permanently ON (output lower than input) and it is downhill from there. Try 95% duty and vary the input voltage with a voltage source and see what your converter does.